# THREE.WEBGLRenderer is not a constructor error in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi can any one help me to solve this error I try to find solution for this but unable to find it

Here is my code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('.cube ')
// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

// Red cube
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1)

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'red'})

const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material)

scene.add(cube)

//  
const size = {
    width:800,
    height:600
}

// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, size.width / size.height)
scene.add(camera)

// renderer

const renderer = new THREE.WEBGLRenderer({
    canvas
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code. `WEBGLRenderer` should be `WebGLRenderer`.